# How to retain only those rows in a matrix corresponding to the values in another matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a m x n matrix A where both m and n are very large values and another column matrix B(which has duplicate values) that contains some row values. I need to create a new matrix that retains only those rows in A that are present in B in that order and discard the rest of them.

Example:

```
A = [2 5 6;
     7 3 9;
    -6 4 5;
     6 7 3];

B = [2;
     4;
     2;
     1];
```

The output C should contain the rows of A as follows:

```
C = [7 3 9;
     6 7 3;
     7 3 9;
     2 5 6];
```

I've used this loop and tried to do it without the need for a new matrix C but it's erroneous.

```
for n = 1:length(B)
   A(~B(n),:)=[];
end
```

Does the solution to the above work the same on a variable if it isn't a matrix but an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about indexing:

```
A = [
  2 5 6;
  7 3 9;
 -6 4 5;
  6 7 3
];

B = [2; 4; 2; 1];

% use B to index the rows of A, basically you
% you tell Matlab to create a new matrix C
% from the rows 2, 4, 2 (again) and 1 of A

C = A(B,:)
```

This outputs:

```
C =

   7  3  9
   6  7  3
   7  3  9
   2  5  6
```